# How to Pass Data from Express Server with NextJS to a Page?

Tags: express, next.js

I have an ExpressJS server with NextJS like shown in the example [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express). There are some pages that I want to server render from my express server.

I came up with the solution below:

```js
// server.js

const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('/server-rendered', (req, res) => {
    // get data from database
    return app.render(req, res, '/server-rendered', { ...req.query, dbData })
  })

  server.all('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res))

  server.listen(3000)
})
```

```js
// pages/server-rendered.js

const ServerRenderedPage = ({ dbData }) => (
    <div>
        {JSON.stringify(dbData, null, 4)}
    </div>
)

export const getServerSideProps = (context) => ({
    props: {
        dbData: context.query.dbData
    }
})

export default ServerRenderedPage
```

The solution above works fine. However, I noticed that in production, when the page is server rendered, the HTML contains a script with the id `__NEXT_DATA__` (to hydrate the page), but it contains the `dbData` both in `pageProps` and in `query` (see below):

```html
<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">
    {
        "props": {
            "pageProps": {
                "dbData": {}
            }
        },
        "query": {
            "dbData": {}
        },
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

So if I pass a big amount of data from my express server, the page will load slower since its size will be way larger that it needs to be, since there is duplicate data in the `__NEXT_DATA__` script tag.

Does anyone have a better solution for how to pass data from custom NextJS server to a page?

I am aware that I can fetch data in `getServerSideProps`, but that is slower than directly rendering a page from a custom NextJS server.

Comment: "that is slower than directly rendering a page from a custom NextJS server" - Can you elaborate as to why fetching the database data would be slower inside `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: @juliomalves I was thinking of the example in NextJS of sending a HTTP request to a server to get data inside `getServerSideProps`, which would be slower than directly fetching the data from the database inside the NextJS server. So yeah, I don't currently see any reason not to fetch data from the DB inside `getServerSideProps` like you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I came up with a solution for how to pass data from an Express NextJS server to a NextJS page without the data being outputted twice in the HTML.

```js
// server.js

server.get('/server-rendered', async (req, res) => {
    // get data from database
    res.dbData = await db.query()

    return app.render(req, res, '/server-rendered', req.query)
})
```

```js
// pages/server-rendered.js

export const getServerSideProps = ({ res }) => ({
    props: {
        dbData: res.dbData
    }
})
```

**Alternatively**, you can fetch data from the database directly inside `getServerSideProps` as @juliomalves suggested, as shown below.

```js
// pages/server-rendered.js

export const getServerSideProps = async context => {
    // get data from database
    const dbData = await db.query()

    return {
        props: {
            dbData
        }
    }
}
```